# Find substring with specific string pattern in php

Tags: php, regex, substring

I want to find substring in a string with **___string_string___** pattern where string_string can be any string.

```
$string = "This string contains ___MY_VALUE___ which I want to replace and there is also ___ONE_MORE_VALUE___ which I want to replace";`
```

Comment: Okay, and what have you done in order to achieve this?

Comment: It is not clear what your `string` part may contain. Please provide the requirements. An example code/regex showing what you tried would also help clearing that out.

Comment: I want to fetch strings with ___value___ pattern and then replace with other value.
e.g: There will be string "This is my ___OTP___" then I will replace ___OTP___ with value like 1234, but there can be multiple __OTP1__,__OTP2__ in a string and I wanted to replace all with different   values.

Comment: show the replacement values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if one string contains another substring in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using [***preg_replace_callback***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with specific regex pattern:

```
// custom replacement list
$pairs = ['___MY_VALUE___' => 123, '___ONE_MORE_VALUE___' => 456];
$str = '"This string contains ___MY_VALUE___ which I want to replace and there is also ___ONE_MORE_VALUE___ which I want to replace";';

$str = preg_replace_callback('/___(([a-z]+_?)+)___/mi', function($m) use($pairs){
    return (isset($pairs[$m[0]]))? $pairs[$m[0]] : $m[0];
}, $str);

print_r($str);
```

The output:

```
"This string contains 123 which I want to replace and there is also 456 which I want to replace";
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you simply want a string & underscores, and nothing else, in between the `___`'s, then;

```
/___([a-zA-Z_]*)___/m
```

[Here's the working example](https://regex101.com/r/NwACGn/1)

**Edit**

To fix the false positive on `______`, I've added a positive lookahead, and made a couple of other tweaks.

```
/_{3}(?=.*[a-zA-Z_])(.*[a-zA-Z_])_{3}/m
```

`_{3}` - Matches 3 underscores

`(?=.*[a-zA-Z_])` - Positive lookahead to make sure one of these characters is present

`(.*[a-zA-Z_])` - The actual matching group

`_{3}` - And match the ending 3 underscores

[Here's a working example of this second version](https://regex101.com/r/NwACGn/2)

Comment: this will also match `_________`

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
$string = "This string contains ___MY_VALUE___ which I want to replace and there is also ___ONE_MORE_VALUE___ which I want to replace";

$replaced = preg_replace_callback("/\___([a-zA-Z_]*)\___/", function($m){
    return "(replaced {$m[1]})";
}, $string);


print_r($replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace everything that is not 3 underscores in between two "3 underscores", use this regex:

```
/___((?:(?!___).)+)___/
```

To replace "keywords" with corresponding values, use preg_replace_callback like that:

```
$replace = array(
'MY_VALUE' => '**Replacement of MY_VALUE**',
'ONE_MORE_VALUE' => '**Replacement of ONE_MORE_VALUE**',
' third value to be replaced ' => '**Replacement of  third value to be replaced**',
);

$string = "This string contains ___MY_VALUE___ which I want to replace 
    and there is also ___ONE_MORE_VALUE___ which I want to replace. 
    This is the ___ third value to be replaced ___";

$string = preg_replace_callback('/___((?:(?!___).)+)___/', 
            function ($m) use($replace){
                return $replace[$m[1]];
            }
            , $string);
echo $string,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
This string contains **Replacement of MY_VALUE** which I want to replace 
and there is also **Replacement of ONE_MORE_VALUE** which I want to replace. 
This is the **Replacement of  third value to be replaced**
```